# Aligning forms horizontally and responsively

Tags: html, css, forms

Suggest me some css which can be applied to get desired output like the ***Image*** below.
I have been trying to align two forms horizontally and one form vertically bottom of my second form. I am also looking to not use **positioning** like *absolute* or *relative* neither **margin properties**.

[My code](http://pastebin.com/Z6WrXabP):

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="shop-menu pull-right" style="color:red;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <form id="sellerLogin" name="sellerLogin" action="/tiles/sellerLogin.action" method="post">
<div id="emailerr">   </div><div id="passerr">    </div><table class="wwFormTable">
                                        <tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="tdLabel">  </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" style="color : #000000;" rel="email" placeholder="Enter email-id.."></td>
</tr>                                          
                                        <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel">    </td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="color : #000000;" placeholder="Enter Password..">     </td>
</tr>`enter code here`<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="right">    <input type="submit" id="sellerLogin_0" value="Login" style="color : #000000;" onclick="return logincheck();">
</div>    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>   </table>    </form>`
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

[Spare me from drawing compliments:).](http://postimg.org/image/930v8ac5n/)

Comment: So you are trying to get both to happen in different positions on the page? To get them side by side you can use `display: inline-block` and then to stack vertically use `display: block; width: 100%;`?

Comment: @Guy Can u tell me where i have to put inline-block in my code.                          And applying `inline-block` to **form id**,**Table class**, Isn't changing anything

Comment: I have inserted your code and images into the question for you. You can further improve the question by pressing the [edit] button. You will note that html, css and javascript can be executed within SO postings by using the code snippet feature. This way people can evaluate your code.